# IronMQ With Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5, message-queue, ironmq

Am trying to implement a mail queue on my godaddy shared hosting using IronMQ but am confused on how to go about creating the queues and linking it with IronMQ. Anybody who has done something similar should help me out.

Note: am new to queues and laravel.